# "context deadline exceeded" error on pod in Kubernetes while pulling a public image of ms sql server

Tags: sql-server, docker, kubernetes

Following Les Jackson's [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DgVjEo3OGBI) on microservices, on local installation of Docker with Kubernetes enabled, I wanted to create a new pod in Kubernetes that would contain an image of ms sql server express, available [here](https://hub.docker.com/_/microsoft-mssql-server). The deployment file is exactly the same as in the video, but I can't get it to work.
Each time the pod ends with status ImagePullBack. After running *kubectl describe pod*:

```
Name:         mssql-depl-5cd6d7d486-nrrkn
Namespace:    default
Priority:     0
Node:         docker-desktop/192.168.65.4
Start Time:   Thu, 28 Jul 2022 12:09:34 +0200
Labels:       app=mssql
              pod-template-hash=5cd6d7d486
Annotations:  <none>
Status:       Pending
IP:           10.1.0.27
IPs:
  IP:           10.1.0.27
Controlled By:  ReplicaSet/mssql-depl-5cd6d7d486
Containers:
  mssql:
    Container ID:
    Image:          mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2017-latest
    Image ID:
    Port:           1433/TCP
    Host Port:      0/TCP
    State:          Waiting
      Reason:       ImagePullBackOff
    Ready:          False
    Restart Count:  0
    Environment:
      MSSQL_PID:    Express
      ACCEPT_EULA:  Y
      SA_PASSWORD:  <set to the key 'SA_PASSWORD' in secret         'mssql'>  Optional: false
    Mounts:
      /var/opt/mssql/data from mssqldb (rw)
      /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount from kube-    api-access-xqzks (ro)
Conditions:
  Type              Status
  Initialized       True
  Ready             False
  ContainersReady   False
  PodScheduled      True
Volumes:
  mssqldb:
    Type:       PersistentVolumeClaim (a reference to a         PersistentVolumeClaim in the same namespace)
    ClaimName:  mssql-claim
    ReadOnly:   false
  kube-api-access-xqzks:
    Type:                    Projected (a volume that contains injected data from multiple sources)
    TokenExpirationSeconds:  3607
    ConfigMapName:           kube-root-ca.crt
    ConfigMapOptional:       <nil>
    DownwardAPI:             true
QoS Class:                   BestEffort
Node-Selectors:              <none>
Tolerations:                 node.kubernetes.io/not-    ready:NoExecute op=Exists for 300s
                                 node.kubernetes.io/unreachable:NoExecute op=Exists for 300s
Events:
  Type     Reason     Age                  From               Message
  ----     ------     ----                 ----               -------
  Normal   Scheduled  3m42s                default-scheduler      Successfully assigned default/mssql-depl-5cd6d7d486-nrrkn to docker-desktop
  Warning  Failed     102s                 kubelet                Failed to pull image "mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2017-latest":     rpc error: code = Unknown desc = context deadline exceeded
  Warning  Failed     102s                 kubelet            Error: ErrImagePull
  Normal   BackOff    102s                 kubelet            Back-off pulling image "mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2017-latest"
  Warning  Failed     102s                 kubelet            Error: ImagePullBackOff
  Normal   Pulling    87s (x2 over 3m41s)  kubelet            Pulling image "mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2017-latest"
```

I discovered the underlying error

> "rpc error: code = Unknown desc = context deadline exceeded"

And I'm not sure how to proceed further to fix this issue, I would really appreciate any help.

I posted this originally on stackoverflow [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73150640/imagepullback-pod-status-in-kubernetes-when-pulling-public-image-ms-sql-server) and was redirected with my issue to this site as it's potentially a networking problem.

Comment: From that node (docker-desktop / 192.168.65.4), have you tried to pull this image? Assuming container runtime is docker: `docker pull  mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2017-latest`. Check systemd logs (all units), that "context deadline exceeded" suggests kubelet could not get an answer from docker in a timely manner: your host could be overloaded, some service could be crashed, ... Can you check back on that pod events: currently we only have one context deadline exceeded, second attempt to pull started: later on, do we still see that same timeout, or do you have anything else?

Comment: The command `docker pull mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2017-latest` worked just fine from powershell on my computer right now. I deleted the deployment afterwards and applied it again and I think it might have fixed the issue as the pod now has a running status. I don't have access to the events from the last pod anymore, but from previous attempts I remember that it continued to timeout until the limit of 5mins was reached. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 3):

I fixed it by running `docker pull mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2017-latest`, deleting and re-applying the deployment.

Comment: That's a workaround I'm using too, it. Problem actually is docker (as the container runtime): https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube/issues/14789#issuecomment-1214395500 - there are internal timeouts and depending on your internet line's speed and image size, you may never successfully pull the image through K8s before the context exceeds. A manual pull doesn't have these restrictions, actually you don't even have to delete the deployment, after pulling the image into local cache, the pod should come up after next try to pull the image (this time from local store in seconds).

Answer (score 3):

Same problem, but I needed to pull the image to minikube first
`minikube ssh docker pull <the_image>`

Then the deployment works

Comment: Source https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube/issues/14806